# On click event not working in JQuery when button has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

Here's my current HTML and JavaScript code:

```
<button class="like_button" th:classappend="${#lists.contains(liked_profiles, profile)} ? unlike : like" th:value="${profile.email}">
   <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" style="font-size:24px"></i>
</button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        $("button.like_button").on('click', function (){
            let email;
            console.log("Got In");
            if($(this).hasClass("like")){
                console.log("Got In if Statement for like");
                email = $(this).val();
                fetch("/api/like/" + email)
                    .then(res => console.log("Response, " + res))
                    .catch(err => console.log("Error, " + err))
                $(this).removeClass("like");
                $(this).addClass("unlike")
            }
            if($(this).hasClass("unlike")){
                console.log("Got In if Statement for unlike");
                email = $(this).val();
                fetch("/api/unlike/" + email)
                    .then(res => console.log("Response, " + res))
                    .catch(err => console.log("Error, " + err))
                $(this).removeClass("unlike");
                $(this).addClass("like");
            }
        });
    });
```

When ever I click on the like button the on click event never runs. Been looking online to see if anyone has had the same issue with no luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Does the button exist before the jQuery code is loaded? Or is it a dynamic button added upon fetching a post with the like button or something like that?

Comment: Hmm, the code you added works fine in Codepen. Are there any other errors you are seeing in the console?

Comment: Is the button dynamically added? For instance only added to the page after some other button click. If so, then the event would not have bound to the element as it didnt exist when the code ran. You would need to use a delegated event listener or run the code after the button was added to the page

Comment: That's interesting it's working on Codepen. The Button is being added through a loop of an object. I'm never able to get the console.log to print so I know I'm never getting into the JavaScript code.

Comment: Code is in HTML but using Thymeleaf to render the pages.

Comment: "The Button is being added through a loop of an object" <= that means it is dynamic content, and the element will not exist at page load time for you to bind on it.

Comment: @Taplar so in that case I'll need a delegated event listener to run the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try change to:

```
$(".like_button").on('click', function (){
```